# getting Instagram access token error

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, social-media

I want to register a new client on the instagram developer page. Therefore I'm going on the API page of instagram, click on "register new client" and fill out the forms with the correct informations.

After pressing the "register" button I permanently get the following error message on a new page:

> **Error**
>
> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your
>   browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling
>   cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.

I tried the same steps with different browsers.

Any Ideas what the problem is and how I can get the access token for my app?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/ "The Developer Dashboard allows you to report issues you find with the Instagram developer platform by clicking on the Report Issue button". Did you try contacting Instagram?

Comment: Yes I've tried to report an issue but I got the following message:
"The Instagram API Platform will be deprecated beginning in July 2018. As a result, we're no longer accepting bug reports for the existing Instagram API. Thanks!"
They also mention to ask in the stack overflow community. So i did :)